# saving data to a csv file from a pandas dataframe with more than one item to append

Tags: python-3.x

I have a lop that opens a text file and appends some of the data to a list then I want to dump the saved data (list) to a csv file

```
my_list = []
with open(fname,'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        if 'text' in line:
            my_list.append(f"{line[2]},{line[10]},{line[5]}")

df = pd.DataFrame(my_list,columns=columns)

# save to csv
df.to_csv('my_file.csv')
```

The problem is that it that every row is saved as a single string (when I open the file in excel ) like this:

```
0, "Red, Orange, Purple"
1, "Orange, Orange, Purple"
2, "White, Black, Purple"
```

I need this to be saved like this:

```
0, Red, Orange, Purple
1, Orange, Orange, Purple
2, White, Black, Purple
```

So that each color is separated into it's own cell.

Comment: the why would you but it in a f-string?

Comment: I need to add more than 1 item per iteration that's why I'm using the f-string.

Comment: But it is also the reason why everything is saved in one string. Why not use a tuple of list and add those to `my_list`

Comment: @chatax Not sure I understand.  Can you put some sample code so that I can follow?

Comment: see my answer down below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use the f-string for this, but use a `tuple` or `list`

```
# tuple:
my_list.append((line[2], line[10], line[5]))

# or a list:
my_list.append([line[2], line[10], line[5]])

# instead of:
my_list.append(f"{line[2]},{line[10]},{line[5]}")
```